# Token longer than max allowable length of 258

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am getting the error "Token longer than max allowable length of 258 " when i run the below control file

```
 fields terminated by '|' trailing nullcols
    (
    numsus,
    mnecau,
    commod,
    snsmvt,
    typcon "CASE when :numsus =29
                then
                    case when :mnecau ='s'
                        then
                            case when :snsmvt = 'c'
                                then 'RECP'
                                 when :snsmvt = 'd'
                                 then 'NLED'
                                 end
                        when :mnecau = 'l'
                        then
                            case when :snsmvt = 'd'
                                then 'FAIL'
                                 when :snsmvt = 'c'
                                 then 'NOPYM'
                                 end         

                        end 

            END"
    )
```

But if i remove the below part of the control file it is working fine

```
when :mnecau = 'l'
                            then
                                case when :snsmvt = 'd'
                                    then 'FAIL'
                                     when :snsmvt = 'c'
                                     then 'NOPYM'
                                     end         

                            end
```

Comment: There's lots of spaces in the CASE statement. What happens if you sacrifice the layout and remove most of them?

Comment: I am removing the space and it is working fine, but what should be the maximum length? Because even if i put 280 chars inside " " it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You could put all that into a function and call that instead.  May I suggest creating a package of your sqlldr-related functions:

```
...
typcon "sqlldr_lib.get_typcon(:numsus, :mnecau, :snsmvt)"
...
```

Its cleaner anyway and it's better practice to encapsulate the code so it is reusable and you only have one place to maintain code.